# read_csv with dypes, thousands and keep_default_na defined

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have an exported Excel CSV file with `str(date), str, float, float, float, float, int` as column values. Some of the Excel cells are empty, thus using `keep_default_na` is needed.
Some are in double quotes, thousand separators present.
The number of parameters seems to confuse the pandas parser because running this outputs:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,917.6'

Seems that when `keep_default_na` is present, `thousands` gets ignored. When I run this without any `,,,,,,` lines in the csv, it works perfectly.

CSV FILE:

```
TS
Date,Symbol,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
6/14/2022 23:59,A,918.1,918.1,918.1,918.1,1
,,,,,,
6/14/2022 23:57,A,"1,917.6",917.6,917.6,917.6,1
,,,,,,
,,,,,,
```

CODE

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',
                 skiprows=1,
                 quotechar='"',
                 thousands=',', 
                 keep_default_na=False,
                 dtype = {'Open': np.float64, 'High': np.float64, 
                          'Low': np.float64, 'Close': np.float64,
                          'Volume': np.uint32, 'Symbol': 'string'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be that the routine which reports which values are the problem isn't as sophisticated as the full parsing engine - I think you have multiple dtype issues in each column and pandas is telling you the wrong value is the actual issue. float columns can't have the value "" (so it needs to be included in a list of na_values), and int columns can't have NA values, so you either need to skip the footer, or provide `na_values` and use float dtypes. Both of the following work for me:

skipfooter works with your arguments, but falls back to the python engine:

```py
In [26]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',
    ...:                  skiprows=1,
    ...:                  quotechar='"',
    ...:                  thousands=",",
    ...:                  keep_default_na=False,
    ...:                  dtype = {'Open': np.float64, 'High': np.float64,
    ...:                           'Low': np.float64, 'Close': np.float64,
    ...:                           'Volume': np.uint32, 'Symbol': 'string'},
    ...:                  skipfooter=2,
    ...: )
```

Alternatively, you could read with float columns and specify [""] as a na_value:

```py
In [29]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',
    ...:                  skiprows=1,
    ...:                  quotechar='"',
    ...:                  thousands=",",
    ...:                  keep_default_na=False,
    ...:                  dtype = {'Open': np.float64, 'High': np.float64,
    ...:                           'Low': np.float64, 'Close': np.float64,
    ...:                           'Volume': np.float32, 'Symbol': 'string'},
    ...:                  na_values=[""],
    ...: )
```

at this point, you could drop rows based on any condition you like, for example, drop rows with NaNs in `'Volume'`, then convert to int:

```py
In [30]: df = df[df.Volume.notnull()]

In [31]: df["Volume"] = df["Volume"].astype(int)
```

Alternatively, you could set an invalid value marker, e.g.:

```py
In [32]: df["Volume"] = df["Volume"].fillna(-9999).astype(int)
```

Comment: skipfooter doesn't help, it's just excluding the empties. With a large number of files I would not know how many rows to skip. I tried na_values before and it has no effect because keep_default_na already determines the na_values correctly by default.

Comment: I'm also getting the exception on a normally valid value ('1,917.6'). Without the empty values, this doesn't get thrown. So I'm guessing completely different methods are used when NAs are present.

Comment: no, `keep_default_na=False` means pandas should *not* use the defualt NA list. I saw the exact same error as you, and gave an explanation for what's going on, with a fix. Feel free to provide an [mre] that actually introduces the error you're trying to solve for. but this correctly reads your example file.

Comment: The MRE does illustrate the problem but I will place the empty line between two valid lines. The number and placement of empty lines is unknown, so skipping last lines won't do any good. I'll edit my question to illustrate it better.

Comment: sounds good. and what's the issue with the second option?

Comment: Second solution with na_values fails with the same error. ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''.

Comment: you provide the `na_values=[""]` and get `could not convert string to float: ""`? can you provide an exact MRE and the version of pandas you're using?

Comment: Using the MRE provided with the same (updated) csv. na_values=[""] fails with ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 6. na_values=[" "] fails with ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''. Pd 1.4.2

Comment: right. my second answer uses `np.float32` for Volume for that reason. You can't have blank values in a numeric column, so they need to be interpreted as NaN. Once you've read in the file, you can drop the NaNs, and then convert the column to integer. There's no way around this if you have invalid data in an int col.

Comment: That one escaped me, sorry. Thanks!

Comment: ahh - should have called that point out. glad it helped!